Xcode not updating Package to latest version, despite correct pushes and tags
I have a Swift package in our Github repo, which has been updated, newly tagged, and pushed. In Github everything shows to be in the correct state (i.e. the updated code is correct).
However, I cannot get Xcode to pull that version. The entry under Package Dependencies shows the correct tag, but the code in the file is an older version. (For what it's worth, it's an import statement that was removed, but is still showing up in Xcode.)
Steps taken:

Update package version
Reset package cache
Resolve package versions
Deleted derived data directory
Deleted org.swift.swiftpm packages

Any insights appreciated.

You didn't say you deleted both org.swift.swiftpm packages. I find that, when a tag has been shifted, that is necessary, so please try it. — Also please note that we have only your word that the file is "in the correct state"; you claim that the tagged commit is in the "correct state", but how do we know? The whole question is indeterminate, lacking any details or facts, and it isn't even really about programming.

By 'correct state' I meant only that the file as viewed on Githib had the correct code. Thank you for your suggestion regarding the org.swift.swiftpm deletion, which sadly didn't work.

Well, I have to suggest that despite your claims, the commits are not correctly configured on GitHub. If you don't wish to expose the repo to public view, there is nothing we can do to assist you.

Check your gitignore. I had /Package in my git ignore and that was the issue.
